# Сервер Flask не хочет обрабатывать хэштеги (#) в route

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Есть `input` в html файле
`<input id="text" placeholder="Текст">`

С помощью JavaScript я получаю с него значение и отправляю на сервер:

```
text = $("#text").val();
var url = "/tweet?text=" + text;
fetch (url)
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
        alert(data["text"]);
    });
```

Route которого выглядит как:

```
@app.route('/tweet')
def tweet():
    text = request.args.get('text', type=str)
    print(text)
    return {"text": text}
```

Если в поле `#text` я пишу текст, включающий в себя хэштег, то на выходе в `alert` получаю только текст, который шел до `#`.

Помогите разобраться в проблеме.

Comment: Urlencode кто будет делать?

Comment: Можете добавить вопрос минимально воспроизводимый пример?
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example